# Update when same table in Select with additional joins

Tags: mysql, updates

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235705/update-table-using-itself-in-select?noredirect=1#comment89450666_51235705) was marked as duplicate but I can't find the answer I'm looking for in there likely because my case is more complex.

If necessary I'll make a SqlFiddle but for now the question is that I am doing something like this:

```
Select if(A.Value>10,concat(A.Field1,B.FIeld),concat(A.Field1,C.Field1)) 
from A
Inner Join B on A.Field3=B.Field3
Inner Join C on A.Field3=C.Field3
```

Trying to use any of the options from the dupe question I point to fails as it means I'm doing another join to this select which, at least for me is impossible and my ultimate update goal here is:

```
Update A set Display=(Select if(A.Value>10,concat(A.Field1,B.FIeld),concat(A.Field1,C.Field1)) 
from A
Inner Join B on A.Field3=B.Field3
Inner Join C on A.Field3=C.Field3)
```

Comment: You did not follow the multi-table update syntax demonstrated in the duplicate topic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want syntax for an update join in MySQL?

```
UPDATE A
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.Field3 = B.Field3
INNER JOIN C
    ON A.Field3 = C.Field3
SET Display = CASE WHEN A.Value > 10
                   THEN CONCAT(A.Field1, B.Field)
                   ELSE CONCAT(A.Field1,C.Field1) END;
```